# Visual Studio Doesn't Recognize Newly Added Files: C1083

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I've started working on a project, at the start I've used `Project -> Add -> Existing Item` to add the starting files. Then, after finishing with those files I tried to add new files using the same method. But now VS throws Error C1083 when I'm trying to use old classes on my newly added classes:

```
#define SYNTAX_EXCEPTION_H

#include "InterperterException" <- C1083

class InterperterException;

class SyntaxException : public InterperterException
{
public:
    SyntaxException();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

#endif // SYNTAX_EXCEPTION_H
```

Now in the Solution Explorer the files clearly seem to exist in the project:

[image]

The weirdest thing is that in the project folder no files at all are seen, but Visual Studio clearly recognizes my old files ( the project run fine before adding the new files ):
[image]

Comment: Is this `#include "InterperterException"` just a typo? You probably intended to write `#include "InterperterException.h"` I guess. There seems to be no file named `InterperterException` (without an extension) among your header files. Which is totally normal, because usually only the standard C++ headers are in files without extension. Traditionally, user-created header files use an `h` or `hpp` filename extension.

Comment: Visual Studio project files (`*.vcxproj`) contain paths to the source (and header) files (among other things). When you use `Add Existing Item` to add already existing files to the project, just the paths of those existing files are saved into the project file, but the files are not copied into the project folder. That's why you don't see these files in the project folder (the files are still in their original location). Normally, when starting a new project, you either `Add New Item` to create a file in the correct folder or you first copy/move an existing file and then `Add Existing Item`.